# My shape keys on one specific model are broken after exporting

Tags: export, shape-keys

I was working on my vtuber model in blender to set up shapekeys for ARkit tracking. I'm very much a blender novice but I've successfully set up a few other shapekeys before and they were tested to be working. After setting up all the keys and their corresponding blendshape proxy settings after exporting the model none of the shape keys are working in the destination program including the shape keys I didn't even edit.. The program is recognizing that the keys all exist but the model will not change under any circumstances including when I would use a hotkey to trigger the key. When I export the reference model I was using in the same file, that model works completely as expected, as does an older version of my model. I meticulously tried to compare every single setting on all the models and they all appear to be identical. The export is only giving me some minor texture warnings that are on all the models that successfully worked. There are no modifiers that were applied after the shape keys either.

Additionally when I import the broken file where none of the shape keys were working into Unity and export it as is with no changes, the model works as expected in the destination program. I worry that I accidentally clicked something or hit some kind of hotkey that is breaking the model after export. I could just import this working vrm file into blender again but I would prefer to fix the original blender file instead. I also am worried about accidentally causing this problem again. Does anyone have any idea what went wrong?